# button issue in html page

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am wondering how to set the default button in html page, so that when enter key is pressed, the same effect of button pressed? For example, when we use Google, after entering query string in the middle input box, we can press enter key to get query results (i.e. press enter has the same effect of click "Google Search" button).

Any solutions? I am not sure whether there are different solutions when it is an html button, and when it is the submit button of a html form?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simply done with a `<form>` element.

For example, if you have something like this:

```
<form action="something.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="blah">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and you press enter in the input field, the form will be posted to something.php, ie. the same as if you press the submit button.

Comment: What happens if multiple forms in the same html page? Which form's submit button is pressed? :-)

Comment: The one you're in, ie if you have two forms with text input fields and you have the cursor in the first one and you press enter, the first form will get submitted.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your form is contained inside a `<form>` tag and you have an input or button of `type="submit"`, it should submit when you hit enter. If those two conditions aren't true, you can use javascript to detect onkeyup for the enter key.

Comment: "you can use javascript to detect onkeyup for the enter key" -- can you show me how? Any samples? :-)

Comment: And for Form, what happens if multiple forms in the same html page? Which form's submit button is pressed? :-)

Comment: submit will trigger parent form.

Comment: Sorry, I do not mean a parent form and another child form inside. I mean two forms of the same html element DOM tree level (i.e. the same hierarchy)?

Comment: He means: submit will trigger the form where the focus is in.